# A certain identity of a Dirichlet series

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series, dirichlet-convolution

I have encountered this problem:
I need to prove that
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{d(n^2)}{n^s} = \frac{\zeta^{3}(s)}{\zeta(2s)}$.
Now, I already know that $\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)} = \sum_{n is square free} \frac{1}{n^s} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{\mu^{2}(n)}{n^s}   $, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{d(n)}{n^s} = \zeta^{2}(s)$ , So this problem can be solved if I can prove this convulation identity: $(\mu^{2} * d)(n) = d(n^{2}) $. I tried some things but it didn't work out, someone can help\have mmaybe another way?

Comment: Have you tried proving your identity just at prime powers $n$? Since the functions are weakly multiplicative, this would suffice, and is often easier to organize.

Comment: This also applies to the original identity: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{d(n^2)}{n^s}=\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{d(p^{2k})}{p^{ks}}=\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2k+1}{p^{ks}};\\\sum_{k=0}^\infty(2k+1)x^k=\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{1-x^2}{(1-x)^3}.$$

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $d(n)=\sum_{d|n}1$ is multiplicative, and $\mu^2(n)$ is also some multiplicative function. Hence, we may consider the prime powers first:

Let $n=p^k$ where $k\ge1$, so
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{m|n}\mu^2(m)d\left(\frac nm\right)
&=\sum_{r=0}^k\mu^2(p^r)d(p^{k-r}) \\
&=\mu^2(1)d(p^k)+\mu^2(p)d(p^{k-1}) \\
&=d(p^k)+d(p^{k-1}) \\
&=2k+1=d(p^{2k})
\end{aligned}
$$

As a result, we have
$$
\sum_{m|n}\mu^2(m)d\left(\frac nm\right)=d(n^2)
$$
which completes the proof.